# Find string using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I Want to Find string ,whose last character may or may not present

```
"abc,efg,ASD"
"abc,ASD,efg"
```

so, i have to find ASD with or without " , "

Comment: `str.match(/\bASD\b/g)`?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match on an element of a comma-separated list? For example, "abc,efg,ASD" or "abc,ASD,efg" should match (looking for ASD) but "abc,efg,ASDF" or "abc,ASDF,efg" should not?

Comment: I read it as if you needed `ASD` from the first string, and `ASD,` from the second. The criteria are not clear: get all non-word chars after ASD but whitespace (`/\bASD[^\w\s]*/`)? Or an optional comma (`/\bASD,?/`)?

Answer (score 2):

## Description

```
[,"](ASD)[,"]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- match the asd between commas or comma and quote,
- place the value into capture group 1

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/mV9vA9/1

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [,"]                     any character of: ',', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ASD                      'ASD'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [,"]                     any character of: ',', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```js
var regex = /,ASD,?/g;
var result = regex.exec("abc,ASD\nabc,ASD,dsa");
console.log(result);
```